# confusion over PHP version in Windows and wamp

Tags: php, windows, environment-variables, wamp

I am running WAMP locally and I have `phpinfo()` showing php version as `5.6.25`
windows powershell shows PHP environment variable as `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25`

but when I'm doing `php -v` the version is showing `7.0.10` and I want the version to be 5.6.* else my Laravel 5.0.* project won't work , so can somebody please tell me which is the correct version of PHP in my system and if it's 7.0 then how to get it to 5.6

Comment: check version of php in environment variable in system and reply me

Answer (score 0):

> `phpinfo()` showing php version as 5.6.25

it means that php of version 5.6.25 was installed in wamp server as module.when phpinfo() executes webserver looks for php module in apache so it return's 5.6.25

> php -v the version is showing 7.0.10

in shell , php version of 7.0.10 was installed as environment variable so it returns php7 .

don't worry php 5 executes when you send request for wamp server

> how to get it to 5.6

set php 5 in environment variables by removing php7

Comment: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25

Comment: set that dir in environment var